# I want to run macro based on value of cell in sheet after it is opened

Tags: excel, ms-access, ms-access-2010, vba

I am assigning value to some cell in sheet1 from MS Access. Then based on that cell value I want to pull data from MS Access Table. If I put select statements in workbook_open event it says that cell value is null. How can this be done. I want to run Select after workbook is loaded with the data. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your select statements in a macro in the excel workbook and add a line at the end of your VBA to run that macro after the key is updated in cell A1. [Here](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/running-an-excel-macro-from-access-or-another-excel-workbook/) is how you can run excel macros from Access.

Comment: Hi Sudhi, Thank you very much for the answer. It worked. Instead of putting in workbook open event I just put select in Macro and run that macro from access.Sub RunExcelMacro()
Dim xl As Object
 
Step 1:  Start Excel, then open the target workbook.
   Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xl.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Book1.xlsm")
 
Step 2:  Make Excel visible
   xl.Visible = True
 
Step 3:  Run the target macro
   xl.Run "MyMacro"
 
Step 4:  Close and save the workbook, then close Excel
   xl.ActiveWorkbook.Close (True)
    xl.Quit
 
Step 5:  Memory Clean up.
   Set xl = Nothing
 
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. verify from Access that the value is in the correct cell of the correct worksheet.
2. save the workbook
3. manually open the workbook
4. manually verify the value is in the correct cell of the correct worksheet
5. verify the workbook open event macro is looking in the proper place.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, But you havent understood issue. Issue is I open workbook from MS Access via VBA and pass some primary key to cell(A,1) in excel. Then from that value I need to pick records from MS Access table and Show in workbook. The value in cell A1 is empty while workbook open event, so I can not pick records at workbook open event. I want to run SQL after that cell A1 is assigned from Access. Please help me out. Thanks